# Why does a resolve() have to happen before a commit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios, vuex

I am working with Vue & Vuex, making a fairly simple axios `DELETE` call to the server inside of a promise.

I noticed that the `DELETE` call was working correctly, the Vuex commit was also working, however my resolve was not.

I got everything to work by placing the resolve() BEFORE my commit(), however I do not understand WHY it needs to happen this way.

Hopefully someone has an answer so I can learn. See code below, and thank you in advance.

```
export const remove = ({ state, commit }, uid) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    t.$axios.delete(t.$consts.DELETE_URL + '/' + uid).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            resolve()
            commit('remove', uid)
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error.response)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: do you get an error (in console for example) if you put it the other way around - i.e. in what way was it "not working" - the only way I can see

Comment: [avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) - your code is better written https://pastebin.com/yFxKdtUa - see if that works for you

Comment: one thing your code assumes is that the `error` in `.catch` will contain a property `.response`

Comment: Can you explain more about what is happen when you put `resolve` after `commit` and how you call this function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about how it "was not working". 

When commit() was placed on the line above resolve(), it wouldn't resolve the promise. 

If I attempted to catch the error, there was none.

I like the links @JaromandaX gave me, I'm going to look more into anti-pattern and see if I can take something away from that.

Comment: so, does https://pastebin.com/yFxKdtUa actually work?

Comment: It does not. Similar issue - the delete occurs on the backend, the commit() updates the local Vuex Store, however I get:

`Uncaught (in promise) undefined `

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this code is a Vuex Action, and the commit is a mutation.

Comment: oh ... `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` ... there's actually an error being thrown by `commit('remove', uid)` - but the error thrown by the commit has no `response` property, hence the catch is doing a `throw undefined` and it is this rejection that is uncaught ... this also explains why your code needs to resolve first, because the commit throws an error ... try https://pastebin.com/hCB1yfCJ ... now you should be able to see what error `commit` is throwing (which was lost in both your code and my previous pastebin

Comment: Found this and it was the answer for me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989588/vuex-action-which-returns-a-promise-never-resolves-or-rejects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989588/vuex-action-which-returns-a-promise-never-resolves-or-rejects)